# How to add a new line before output in xfce4-terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, newline, xfce

I want a to add some padding to outputs in the terminal like this

```
prompt >> command

output

prompt >> command
```

I know how to add a newline after the output, by appending a `'\n'` before `PS1`.
However how do I add a newline after every command I enter.

Is there any other way to achieve this padding in `xfce-4 terminal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trap echo DEBUG
PS1="prompt >> "
```

`trap` with DEBUG will run `echo` to create a newline before every command

Comment: This is what I used `trap 'printf "\n\n"' DEBUG`